# Isotope combination filters with select (dropdown)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-isotope, jquery-masonry

I am trying to use 2 select dropdown menus to display filtering options for my Isotope grid.

I have been trying to follow Isotope docs on the filtering but i am a bit stuck when it comes to having 2 select menus. The docs only provide examples of multiple sets of buttons working in combination together (not selects)

Here is my work so far: https://codepen.io/whitinggg/pen/pLMdWB

If you select "Sector One" from the first select, and "Service Two" from the second select menu you will see my problem. The filtering is not combining the options together, instead showing all results.

Can anyone help me fix the JS to combine both selects together to show the correct results?

```
HTML
<div class="grid-filter">

  <select class="filters-select">
    <option value="*">All Sectors</option>
    <option value=".sector-one">Sector One</option>
    <option value=".sector-two">Sector Two</option>
  </select>

  <select class="filters-select">
    <option value="*">All Services</option>
    <option value=".service-one">Service One</option>
    <option value=".service-two">Service Two</option>
  </select>

</div>

<div class="grid">

  <div class="grid-sizer"></div>
  <div class="gutter-sizer"></div>

  <div class="grid-item service-one sector-one">
    <div class="item-cover">
      <div class="item-cover-img">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/800/400">
      </div>
      <div class="item-cover-caption">
        <div class="">
          <p>Project 1</p>
        </div>
        <div class="">
          <p><a>Icon</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item-content">
      <div class="">
        <h1>Project Title</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris tortor dui, pretium id est quis, aliquam fermentum diam. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas risus augue, pretium ac ornare sit amet, suscipit at massa. Mauris non leo molestie, pellentesque lacus vel, lobortis dolor. Nunc fermentum sollicitudin arcu sit amet cursus. Morbi eu risus gravida, finibus augue iaculis, luctus massa. Ut sit amet aliquet nisl. Suspendisse tincidunt accumsan est, luctus pretium nulla condimentum ac. Donec vel diam nec augue mattis vulputate. Nulla facilisi. In velit magna, venenatis id enim feugiat, convallis pulvinar neque. Fusce id accumsan orci, quis fringilla tellus. Curabitur non ligula sed orci semper sodales. Nunc quis porta leo, vel condimentum lacus.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris tortor dui, pretium id est quis, aliquam fermentum diam. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas risus augue, pretium ac ornare sit amet, suscipit at massa. Mauris non leo molestie, pellentesque lacus vel, lobortis dolor. Nunc fermentum sollicitudin arcu sit amet cursus. Morbi eu risus gravida, finibus augue iaculis, luctus massa. Ut sit amet aliquet nisl. Suspendisse tincidunt accumsan est, luctus pretium nulla condimentum ac. Donec vel diam nec augue mattis vulputate. Nulla facilisi. In velit magna, venenatis id enim feugiat, convallis pulvinar neque. Fusce id accumsan orci, quis fringilla tellus. Curabitur non ligula sed orci semper sodales. Nunc quis porta leo, vel condimentum lacus.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/800/400" class="">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="grid-item service-two sector-one">
    <div class="item-cover">
      <div class="item-cover-img">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/800/400">
      </div>
      <div class="item-cover-caption">
        <div class="">
          <p>Project 2</p>
        </div>
        <div class="">
          <p><a>Icon</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item-content">
      <div class="">
        <h1>Project Title</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris tortor dui, pretium id est quis, aliquam fermentum diam. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas risus augue, pretium ac ornare sit amet, suscipit at massa. Mauris non leo molestie, pellentesque lacus vel, lobortis dolor. Nunc fermentum sollicitudin arcu sit amet cursus. Morbi eu risus gravida, finibus augue iaculis, luctus massa. Ut sit amet aliquet nisl. Suspendisse tincidunt accumsan est, luctus pretium nulla condimentum ac. Donec vel diam nec augue mattis vulputate. Nulla facilisi. In velit magna, venenatis id enim feugiat, convallis pulvinar neque. Fusce id accumsan orci, quis fringilla tellus. Curabitur non ligula sed orci semper sodales. Nunc quis porta leo, vel condimentum lacus.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris tortor dui, pretium id est quis, aliquam fermentum diam. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas risus augue, pretium ac ornare sit amet, suscipit at massa. Mauris non leo molestie, pellentesque lacus vel, lobortis dolor. Nunc fermentum sollicitudin arcu sit amet cursus. Morbi eu risus gravida, finibus augue iaculis, luctus massa. Ut sit amet aliquet nisl. Suspendisse tincidunt accumsan est, luctus pretium nulla condimentum ac. Donec vel diam nec augue mattis vulputate. Nulla facilisi. In velit magna, venenatis id enim feugiat, convallis pulvinar neque. Fusce id accumsan orci, quis fringilla tellus. Curabitur non ligula sed orci semper sodales. Nunc quis porta leo, vel condimentum lacus.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/800/400" class="">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="grid-item service-two sector-two">
    <div class="item-cover">
      <div class="item-cover-img">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/800/400">
      </div>
      <div class="item-cover-caption">
        <div class="">
          <p>Project 3</p>
        </div>
        <div class="">
          <p><a>Icon</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item-content">
      <div class="">
        <h1>Project Title</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris tortor dui, pretium id est quis, aliquam fermentum diam. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas risus augue, pretium ac ornare sit amet, suscipit at massa. Mauris non leo molestie, pellentesque lacus vel, lobortis dolor. Nunc fermentum sollicitudin arcu sit amet cursus. Morbi eu risus gravida, finibus augue iaculis, luctus massa. Ut sit amet aliquet nisl. Suspendisse tincidunt accumsan est, luctus pretium nulla condimentum ac. Donec vel diam nec augue mattis vulputate. Nulla facilisi. In velit magna, venenatis id enim feugiat, convallis pulvinar neque. Fusce id accumsan orci, quis fringilla tellus. Curabitur non ligula sed orci semper sodales. Nunc quis porta leo, vel condimentum lacus.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris tortor dui, pretium id est quis, aliquam fermentum diam. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas risus augue, pretium ac ornare sit amet, suscipit at massa. Mauris non leo molestie, pellentesque lacus vel, lobortis dolor. Nunc fermentum sollicitudin arcu sit amet cursus. Morbi eu risus gravida, finibus augue iaculis, luctus massa. Ut sit amet aliquet nisl. Suspendisse tincidunt accumsan est, luctus pretium nulla condimentum ac. Donec vel diam nec augue mattis vulputate. Nulla facilisi. In velit magna, venenatis id enim feugiat, convallis pulvinar neque. Fusce id accumsan orci, quis fringilla tellus. Curabitur non ligula sed orci semper sodales. Nunc quis porta leo, vel condimentum lacus.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/800/400" class="">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="grid-item service-two sector-two">
    <div class="item-cover">
      <div class="item-cover-img">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/800/400">
      </div>
      <div class="item-cover-caption">
        <div class="">
          <p>Project 4</p>
        </div>
        <div class="">
          <p><a>Icon</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item-content">
      <div class="">
        <h1>Project Title</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris tortor dui, pretium id est quis, aliquam fermentum diam. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas risus augue, pretium ac ornare sit amet, suscipit at massa. Mauris non leo molestie, pellentesque lacus vel, lobortis dolor. Nunc fermentum sollicitudin arcu sit amet cursus. Morbi eu risus gravida, finibus augue iaculis, luctus massa. Ut sit amet aliquet nisl. Suspendisse tincidunt accumsan est, luctus pretium nulla condimentum ac. Donec vel diam nec augue mattis vulputate. Nulla facilisi. In velit magna, venenatis id enim feugiat, convallis pulvinar neque. Fusce id accumsan orci, quis fringilla tellus. Curabitur non ligula sed orci semper sodales. Nunc quis porta leo, vel condimentum lacus.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris tortor dui, pretium id est quis, aliquam fermentum diam. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas risus augue, pretium ac ornare sit amet, suscipit at massa. Mauris non leo molestie, pellentesque lacus vel, lobortis dolor. Nunc fermentum sollicitudin arcu sit amet cursus. Morbi eu risus gravida, finibus augue iaculis, luctus massa. Ut sit amet aliquet nisl. Suspendisse tincidunt accumsan est, luctus pretium nulla condimentum ac. Donec vel diam nec augue mattis vulputate. Nulla facilisi. In velit magna, venenatis id enim feugiat, convallis pulvinar neque. Fusce id accumsan orci, quis fringilla tellus. Curabitur non ligula sed orci semper sodales. Nunc quis porta leo, vel condimentum lacus.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/800/400" class="">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

CSS
* { box-sizing: border-box; }

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

/* ---- grid ---- */

.grid {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

/* clear fix */
.grid:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

/* ---- .grid-item ---- */

.grid-item {
  float: left;
  width: 49%;
}

.grid-item img {
  width: 100%;
}

.grid-item:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.grid-item.gigante {
  width: 99%;
  background-color: grey;
}

.grid-sizer {
  width: 50%;
}

.gutter-sizer {
  width: 1%;
}

.grid-item-content {
  display: none;
}

.item-cover-caption {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 4px;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 0 20px;
    background-color: #2479ffa3;
}


.grid-item.gigante .item-cover {
    display: none;
}

.item-content {
    display: none;
}

.grid-item.gigante .item-content {
    display: flex;
}

.grid-item.gigante .item-content div {
    width: 50%;
    padding: 20px;
}

.grid-filter {
    max-width: 1200px;
    margin: 20px auto;
}

JS
// external js: isotope.pkgd.js

var $grid = $('.grid').isotope({
  itemSelector: '.grid-item',
  layoutMode: 'packery',
  columnWidth: '.grid-sizer',
  packery: {
    gutter: '.gutter-sizer'
  }
});

$grid.on( 'click', '.grid-item', function() {
  // change size of item by toggling gigante class
  $( this ).toggleClass('gigante');
  $grid.isotope('layout');
});

var filterFns = $('.filters-select').on( 'change', function() {
  // get filter value from option value
  var filterValue = this.value;
  // use filterFn if matches value
  filterValue = filterFns[ filterValue ] || filterValue;
  $grid.isotope({ filter: filterValue });
});
```

Comment: Full answer for this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50451048/isotope-filtering-issues-when-reset-to-start-position

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After posting the question i continued to explore the documentation and examples. Which resulted in the following code fixing my issue.

```
$(function() {
    var $container = $('.grid'),
        $select = $('div#filterGroup select');
    filters = {};

    $container.isotope({
        itemSelector: '.grid-item'
    });
        $select.change(function() {
        var $this = $(this);

        var $optionSet = $this;
        var group = $optionSet.attr('data-filter-group');
    filters[group] = $this.find('option:selected').attr('data-filter-value');

        var isoFilters = [];
        for (var prop in filters) {
            isoFilters.push(filters[prop])
        }
        var selector = isoFilters.join('');

        $container.isotope({
            filter: selector
        });

        return false;
    });

});
```